# Does Advance Custom Fields work in Tailpress Theme?

Tags: wordpress, tailwind-css, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently building a new website for a client.

Normally we always use the understrap theme internally to implement websites with ACF.

Since I find the development of Tailwind better than that of Bootstrap, I wanted to try the WP theme with Tailwind - Tailpress.

This works quite well so far. Only when I create a Flexible Content I don't get the data on the page.

I proceeded as with understrap.

You can find the code snippets and images in the post.

Tailpress index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container mx-auto my-8">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'offset' => '1',


    );
    $the_new_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($the_new_query->have_posts() ) {
        // Start the Loop.
        while ( $the_new_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_new_query->the_post();

            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */


            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
        }
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    }
    ?>

</div>

<?php
get_footer();
```

content.php

```
Test
<?php
/**
 * Partial template for content in page.php
 *
 * @package UnderStrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>

<?php
// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows( 'flex_content' ) ):
echo('Test2');
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( the_flexible_field('flex_content') ) : the_row();

        // initialize item iteraton container
        $item_iterator++;

        ?>
        <?php if (!post_password_required()): ?>
        <div class="<?php echo get_row_layout(); ?>" id="ce-item-<?php echo $item_iterator; ?>">
            <?php
            // get content element partials (files should have same name as layout field name)
            include('partials/' . get_row_layout() . '.php');

            ?>

        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php

    endwhile;

endif;
?>
```

[image]

All I get is the first "Test" the "Test 2" is not showing up.. so the if conditions throws the error.

I tried the exact same thing with the understrap theme... everything works there and the data is displayed correctly on the page.